# Import pandas dataframe into MS Access table with python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ms-access

I'm pretty new to python and am trying to implement some automation for my job. Currently I'm trying to update an Access table with data from a CSV through python. So far I have read the CSV into a pandas dataframe and am attempting to add rows one at a time into Access. This is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import pypyodbc
import glob

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", header = 0, low_memory = False)
df = df[['Description','SN','Attribute_1','Attribute_2',\
    'Attribute_3','Attribute_4','Cost','Date']]

con = pypyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver \ 
(*.mdb)};UID=admin;UserCommitSync=Yes;Threads=3;SafeTransactions=0;\
PageTimeout=5;MaxScanRows=8;MaxBufferSize=2048;FIL=MS\
Access;DriverId=25;DefaultDir= \ 
C:/Users/testuser/Documents;DBQ=C:/Users/testuser/ \ 
Documents/Python/test.mdb;')

cursor = con.cursor()

for row in df.iterrows():
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test.table1([Description],[SN], 
      [Attribute_1], [Attribute_2],[[Attribute_3],[Attribute_4],\
      [Cost],[Date]) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", (row[0], row[1] ,\
      row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7]))
    con.commit()
cursor.close()
con.close()
```

Whenever I run this, I ended up getting the error

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I've looked up the typical cause of this, which is said to be wrong indexing (i.e. starting at 1 instead of 0 with python), and ensured I started with 0 index.

I have also looked everywhere I can think of for documentation on how the cursor.execute command works, but am still confused and not sure I have the right syntax for that statement. Any help would be appreciated!

Sample data:

```
Description   SN      Attr_1    Attr_2  Attr_3  Attr_4  Cost    Date
type_a      12938475  shiney    black    hard     a     1.09   7/20/18
type_b      18293940  matt      silver   soft     b     0.56   7/20/2018
type_d      18283940  matt      gray     soft     c     0.78   7/16/2018
type_a      18944938  shiney    silver   medium   d     3.4    7/18/2018
type_a      17485003  matt      silver   hard     v     2.3    7/17/2018
```

Answer (score 0):

"I've looked up the typical cause of this, which is said to be wrong indexing (i.e. starting at 1 instead of 0 with python), and ensured I started with 0 index."

This is also caused when you exceed the expected data or when you reach end of file.

For ex.

```
>>t = (1,2,3)
>>t(2)
3
>>t(3)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Please check for this. Also if this doesn't workout please upload the 'data.csv' to your drive and send the shareable link so that we can run the code and test it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. I added a sample of what the data would look like above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, presumably you do some analytics in Python, save the results as a CSV, and you want to import that because you have some unique ID that you are mapping to, right.  Just do this.

```
  DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "", "Table1", "C:\your_path\testing.csv", True, ""
' where table1 is your table
```

I don't think it's any more complicated than that.  Post back if I missed the point, and you are actually trying to do something else.

Answer (score 0):

Since September 2019, the [sqlalchemy-access](https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-access/) dialect has been available. It allows us to use pandas `.to_sql()` to upload a DataFrame to Access.

(I am the current maintainer of the dialect.)